# How do I test if an index is a valid, non-negative index for 'mystr'?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function called valid_index that takes two parameters, `index` and `mystr`.  The value of index will be an integer, and mystr will be a non-empty string. The function should return True if index is a valid non-negative index for indexing into `mystr`, and returns False if it is not a valid non-negative index.

I tried this, which did not work:

```
def valid_index(index, mystr):
    if index<0 or index>len(mystr-1):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small fix on the `len` instruction

```
def valid_index(index, mystr):
    if index<0 or (index>len(mystr)-1):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to subtract from `mystr`, which won't work. You can only subtract from numbers, not strings.

There's no need to subtract anything, just use `>=` instead of `>`.

```
def valid_index(index, mystr):
    if index<0 or index>=len(mystr):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

There's also no need for `if`, just return the result of the inverted test:

```
def valid_index(index, mystr):
    return index >= 0 and index < len(mystr)
```